# Swift UI Scroll View: Set frame for drag indicator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have following problem. I want to create a vertical `ScrollView` with many rows. At the bottom of the view I have an info bar which appears over the scroll view because I put all the items in a `ZStack`. Here is my code and what it produces:

```swift
struct ProblemView: View {
    

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100, id:\.self) {i in
                        HStack {
                            Text("Text \(i)")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding()
                        Divider()
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Text("Some Info here")
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                
            }
            
        }
    }

    
}

struct ProblemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProblemView()
    }
}
```

[image: GIF]

As you can see the drag indicator is hidden behind the info frame. Also the last item can't be seen because it is also behind the other frame. What

I want is that the drag indicator stops at this info frame. Why am I using a `ZStack` and not just a `VStack`? I want that this opacity effect behind the info frame, you get when you scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A edit on my preview post has been added and therefore I cannot edit it... I am just gonna post the answer as an other one then.

This is the code that fixes your problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProblemView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        
        
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<100, id:\.self) {i in
                HStack {
                    Text("Text \(i)")
                      .foregroundColor(.red)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                      .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding()
                Divider()
            }
      }
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) { // 
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                Text("Some Info here")
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            
        }
  }
}
}

struct ProblemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProblemView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. I have never heard of this modifier. Yeah but this is exactly what I want. Huge thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot control offset of indicator, but we can make all needed views visible by injecting last empty view with the same height (calculated dynamically) as info panel.

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

```
struct ProblemView: View {
    @State private var viewHeight = CGFloat.zero


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {

                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100, id:\.self) {i in
                        HStack {
                            Text("Text \(i)")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding()
                        Divider()

                    }
                    Color.clear
                        .frame(minHeight: viewHeight)     // << here !!
                }
            }

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Text("Some Info here")
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                })

            }

        }
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) {
            self.viewHeight = $0
        }
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}
```